# In C#, can I use reflection to determine if an enum type is int, byte, short, etc?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, types

Is this possible?  I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: For WinRT: type.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum;

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(YourEnum))
```